# Installing Ubuntu, asks for user/pass

Tags: system-installation

Im trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 64bit on my pc. Unfortunately when I try to boot the installation from my usb-drive the installation begins with asking for a username and password..

I didn't set up a user or a password for that matter, so what username/pass should I fill in. I already tried to submit the form blank and with root / root but without success..

Somebody knows what the right combination is or explain if I'm a complete idiot for not understanding what to do..

Thank you all!

Comment: How did you create the USB? Was it from the raw .iso from Ubuntu.com? Also, has it been booted by someone else, who may have added a login to it?

Comment: @Nerdfest I created it following the intstructions on the downloadpage: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download so, yes with the raw iso. And nobody has booted it before.

Comment: May be you had set the password for the HDD drive from bios section.

Answer (score 1):

Try ubuntu and leave the password blank. That is the default on live systems. However, live systems don't normally require you to login, so you might have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing, then it isn't asking you FOR a username and password; it is asking you to PICK one.  You obviously can't be asked to enter a password you haven't chosen yet.

Comment: Yes you would think that but unfortunately every combination I tried results in something like "authentication failed.." so it looks like I need to login..

Comment: @NickGreen are you sure you are installing and not trying to boot an already installed system where someone has set a password?  If you followed the instructions as you said then only the former should be possible, so something isn't adding up.

Comment: Yes I'm sure.. But I heard yesterday that the 64-bit version is not very stable.. So I think I'll wait a couple of months before giving it a try! Thank you for your time!

Comment: @NickGreen you heard wrong; 64bit is just as stable as 32bit.